# Understanding how the Django Auth app creates its tables

Tags: python, sql, django, django-authentication

In the [`models.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py) file of the [Django auth app](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth), there are models for `user` and `group` which create their respective tables in the database:

- `class user` -> `auth_user`
- `class group` -> `auth_group`

There is no class `user_groups`, and yet something fancy happens behind the scenes to also create a table `auth_user_groups` which tracks which users are in which groups. (Each row contains a single `user_id` and `group_id`).

Can someone help me understand how this happens? I may want to replicate this functionality in my own app, where I associate `customer` models with a `group_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User and Groups share a ManyToMany relationship.

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

> groups
>
> Many-to-many relationship to Group

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups

Comment: I see. That's all. I thought it was more complicated... thank you!